# info.php file not found with nginx and php on Mac

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, mac

I have tried to put php file `info.php` inside `/usr/local/www/nginx` folder.  For url `http://test.com/info.php`, it's giving me the error `404 - Not found`.

I am able to access `index.html` file in url `http://test.com`

My server configuration in `nginx.conf` file is as follows.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  test.com www.test.com;
    root /usr/local/www/nginx;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page      500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/local/www/nginx-dist;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Please suggest what I am missing. Thanks.

My error_log is as follows -

```
2015/09/08 09:13:06 [notice] 8965#0: using the "kqueue" event method
2015/09/08 09:13:06 [notice] 8965#0: nginx/1.7.7
2015/09/08 09:13:06 [notice] 8965#0: built by clang 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
2015/09/08 09:13:06 [notice] 8965#0: OS: Darwin 14.4.0
2015/09/08 09:13:06 [notice] 8965#0: hw.ncpu: 4
2015/09/08 09:13:06 [notice] 8965#0: net.inet.tcp.sendspace: 131072
2015/09/08 09:13:06 [notice] 8965#0: kern.ipc.somaxconn: 128
2015/09/08 09:13:06 [notice] 8965#0: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 2560:9223372036854775807
2015/09/08 09:13:06 [notice] 8966#0: start worker processes
2015/09/08 09:13:06 [notice] 8966#0: start worker process 8967
2015/09/08 09:13:06 [notice] 8966#0: start worker process 8968
2015/09/08 09:13:06 [notice] 8966#0: signal 23 (SIGIO) received
2015/09/08 09:13:11 [crit] 8968#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: test.com, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "test.com"
2015/09/08 09:13:11 [error] 8968#0: *1 open() "/usr/local/www/nginx-dist/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: test.com, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock", host: "test.com"
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include debug-level nginx logs for the failing request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last 2 lines in error log you posted shows php-fpm did not create sock-file.

Please check if you have correct configuration in pool configuration file of php-fpm, and it may looks like this :

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

The default listener of php-fpm is `127.0.0.1:9000`.

You may need following nginx configuration if you find there is no `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock` , either do not know how to find & adjust pool configuration.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files      $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Hi Joe, php-fpm has not created the sock file but what may be the reason for this and how to create the sock file.

Comment: Answer revised.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem:

```
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
```

This doesn't correspond to the document root you set. I'm not sure where you found this configuration, but it's broken.

This should read:

```
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I tried to change the configuration as you suggested, but still I am not able to access info.php file.

Answer (score 0):

The second-last line in your error log is the proximate cause of your problem: PHP-FPM isn't running, or it's listening on a different socket.  You'll either need to fix the `fastcgi_pass` config parameter to point to the correct PHP-FPM socket, or else get PHP-FPM running correctly and listening to the socket specified in your config.

Comment: Thanks. But I have checked PHP-FPM Running. Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: php-fpm   52191   abhi    6u  IPv4 0x56485663e5f242e1      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
php-fpm   52192   abhi    0u  IPv4 0x56485663e5f242e1      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
php-fpm   52193   abhi    0u  IPv4 0x56485663e5f242e1      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
php-fpm   52194   abhi    0u  IPv4 0x56485663e5f242e1      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)

Comment: Yes, sorry for that but in comment I could not find the option to format the text properly.

Comment: Edit the information into your question, rather than putting it into a comment.  Many people don't read comments on answers to find out information about the question.